# Twitter bootstrap carousel image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I am using the following markup for twitter bootstrap but the issue I have is that images are left justified whereas I would like them in the center. Is there something obvious that I have missed out?

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
 <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
 <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
 <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
 </ol>
 
<!-- Carousel items -->
             <div class="carousel-inner">
             <div class="active item">
             <img src="images/karyotype2.jpg" alt=""/>
             <div class="carousel-caption">
             <h4>First Thumbnail label</h4>
             <p>Text</p>
             </div>
             </div>
             
             <div class="item">
             <img src="images/Karyotype1.jpg" alt=""/>
             <div class="carousel-caption">
             <h4>Second</h4>
             <p>Text</p>
             </div>
             </div>
             </div>
            <!-- Carousel nav -->
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
  .carousel-inner .item img{
   margin:0 auto; 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a very easy way to fix this issue in my case, by add `width="100%"` in the img tag

```
<img src="images/intro1.jpg" alt="" width="100%">
```

I have big images in the carousel. so this works perfect. When the browser size changes, the images will grow or shrink automatically.